# Trying to figure out a way to swap characters within a string (python)

Tags: python, random, swap

I'm trying to get two random characters inside a word (not first or last) and swap them. Ex. word = wrod, what = waht. My code however, just replaces the first random letter with the second random letter instead of swapping them. Is there a way around this?

```
#Input
word = str(input("Please enter your word here: "))

#Processing/Functions/Output

#Only scramble if word has more than 3 letters
if len(word) > 3:
    
    #randompick picks random positions in the word 
    def randompick() :
        #Pick random positions
        pos1 = randint(1, len(word)-2) 
        pos2 = randint(1, len(word)-2)
        
        #Make sure second position isn't the same as the first
        while pos1 == pos2:
            pos2 = randint(1, len(word)-2)
        
        #assign letters to variables
        firstLetter = word[pos1]
        secondLetter = word[pos2]
        #run scramble function
        #return firstLetter, secondLetter
        
        scramble(firstLetter, secondLetter)
        
    #scramble swaps the two positions previously chosen in randompick  
    def scramble(firstLetter, secondLetter):
        scrambled_word = word.replace(firstLetter, secondLetter) #first replacement
        print (scrambled_word)
    
    #Run functions
    randompick()

else:
    print (word)
```

Answer (score 0):

use the function pop, this will remember and delete the char by index.
convert the string to word first tho, as shown here.

```py
word = ['w','o','r','d'];

print("result before swap: ", word)

randompos1 = 1
randompos2 = 2

word.insert(randompos1, word.pop(randompos2))
word.insert(randompos2, word.pop(randompos1+1))

print("result after swap: ", word)
```

Comment: This will not work. Python strings are immutable so you can change a specific character like that.

Comment: is there a way to swap the letters and then put them into the word? I think your method would swap the letters but is there a way to apply the swap inside the word? So that word=wrod

Comment: i recommend making a list of the word, then switch the indexes as i showed above.

Comment: I changed it to the correct code, copy and paste it to see how it works

Answer (score 0):

Your "random" code looks fine, but yes, the problem is with your replace. I suggest using python list slicing.

```py
firstLetter = word[pos1]
secondLetter = word[pos2]

if pos1 > pos2:
    before = word[:pos1]
    between = word[pos1 + 1:pos2]
    after = word[pos2 + 1:]
    print(before + secondLetter + between + firstLetter + after)
else:
    before = word[:pos2]
    between = word[pos2 + 1:pos1]
    after = word[pos1 + 1:]
    print(before + secondLetter + between + firstLetter + after)
```